# How to remove array in this form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

This code when executed in the console resulted in: `["["2","0","2","0"]"]`, i want to get the year. for example i.e 2020

```rb
@years = Task
           .where(id: params[:id])
           .map { |u| u.created_at.year}.to_s.split(//)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to edit your question to be clearer about what you are trying to accomplish. There is a guide to [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that can help you. Your code 1) creates an array of years, then 2) converts that entire array into a single formatted string, and then 3) splits that string into an array of characters. At a guess I'd say you've got the ``}`` in the wrong place, but without knowing really what you want it's impossible to say.

Comment: What is the need of  `to_s.split(//)`.
Remove `to_s.split(//)` and you will get your answer.

Comment: @ernedo : The result of `map` is an Array. Why do you apply `.to_s` to an array? I don't know the background for your code, but since you seem to  assume that the `where` returns exactly one row, I wonder why you don't simply do a `.where(id: params[:id]).first.created_at.year.to_s`.

Comment: Why is it `@years`, i.e. plural? Are you expecting more than one result?

Comment: i need to separate in string and split to sum all my number, 
However ".where(id: params[:id]).first.created_at.year.to_s" an error occured, undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 1):

[`where`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) returns an array even if it's only one item. You can use [find](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class) instead of where

To get the year:

```rb
# use first to get the first element of the array
@years = Task.where(id: params[:id]).first.created_at.year
# or use find method
@years = Task.find(params[:id]).created_at.year
```

Comment: `#where` returns an ActiveRecord relation, not an array

Comment: @years = Task.find(params[:id]).created_at.year
, Couldn't find Task without an ID,,,,,

Comment: @years = Task.where(id: params[:id]).first.created_at.year
, undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Appears that params[:id] is nil, make sure to check params[:id] value